# How did H.R. 8393 not pass the Senate?

Tags: united-states, senate, specific-legislation, puerto-rico

Who was against it? Surely a majority of Democrats would be in favor of having another Democratic seat, to say nothing of the horrendously undemocratic status quo?

Did the Republicans threaten to filibuster it? All Wikipedia says is it "died" on the Senate floor.

H.R 8393 would have given Puerto Rico and Guam the option to have a referendum which would have given them the vote.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of context what H.R. 8393 is about?

Comment: @quarague Considering the tagging I think this is talking about https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/8393/text

Comment: This question is probably a legitimate one, but something more than a bill number devoid of even a mention of what it is about or which Congress it was introduced in is too bare bones. Assuming an obvious outcome without explaining substantive why is insufficiently detailed. If edited to add detail it would very likely be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

H.R. 8393, which would have created a binding referendum on the status of Puerto Rico, passed in the House of Representatives on December 15, 2022 by 233 to 191. However it still needed to pass in the Senate, which was the problem. According to the *New York Times* (["House Passes Bill That Could Pave the Way for Puerto Rican Statehood"](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/12/15/us/politics/house-puerto-rican-statehood.html), New York Times, December 15, 2022), while the Democratic Party is pro-statehood, the Republican party is not, and according to the *Times* they threatened a filibuster in the Senate in 2022. This meant the bill could not pass in the Senate.

After January 2023 when the Republicans took control of the House of Representatives, there was no possibility of further legislation in the lower house, and no chance of the bill passing in the Senate either. So the bill was effectively dead, pending some change either in Senate composition, Republican Party support for independence, or in Senate voting rules (abolition of the filibuster). The question of why Republicans are opposed to Puerto Rico statehood is a separate matter, but the prospect of more Democratic senators and representatives must factor into it.

In reality, it's not clear that the bill would have led immediately to statehood even if it had passed, because there is a long history of referenda being ignored and calls for new votes, committees, inquiries, and other delays. See e.g. the [Wikipedia article on the Puerto Rico Statehood Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Rico_statehood_movement).

Comment: Note also that the bill had under 20 days days to pass in the Senate because when congress adjourns, all bills not passed "die" and have to be reintroduced (with votes in both houses). This time was also cut short by the Christmas break. Even bills with near unanimous bipartisan support like [H.R. 4785](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/4785) "died" this way.

Comment: @xyldke How often does Congress "adjourn"? Do you mean the two year terms?

Comment: @Trilarion Yes. Granted, adjournment ist perhaps not the best term because it also refers to the end of each day's business and not just the end of the entire two year session.